# LocalStorage multiple list display in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a trouble on how can I display list in my dropdown multiple using LocalStorage.The problem is after saving localstorage When I go back again to my modal like the image below in dropdown, the list didn't show , I just want to display list in dropdown those saved in localstorage. , Is there any expert know about this? thanks in advance.

[image]

> This is what I tried

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="storagelocal()">Search</button>
```

> select option

```
 <select class="select2 form-control" multiple="multiple" name="batch[]" id="batch[]">
    <optgroup label="Mountain Time Zone">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2" >2</option>
    <option value="3" >3</option>
    <option value="4" >4</option>
    <option value="5" >5</option>
    <option value="6" >6</option>
</optgroup>
                                    
</select>
```

> Javascript

```
#setting the list
      function storagelocal(){
        var selected = document.getElementById('#batch[]').value; # dropdown Id for payroll batch
        localStorage.setItem("selected", JSON.stringify(selected));

       }

    #getting the list
    function load_address(){
      var batches = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selected'));
      $('#batch[]').val(batches);
      $('#batch[]').change();
    }
```

Comment: And what happened that didn't work?

Comment: @expressjs123 thanks for your response .When I going back to my modal like the image above in my dropdown the list didn't show , I just want to display list in dropdown those saved in localstorage

Answer (score 0):

To take value from multi-select you have to take it one by one.

```
function storagelocal(){
  const options = document.getElementById('batch[]').options;
  var selected = [];
  Array.from(options).map((option) => {
    if (option.selected) {
      selected.push(option.value);
    }
  });
  localStorage.setItem("selected", JSON.stringify(selected));
}
```

to set multiple value `options` on a multi-select, you need to manually add selected attributes to the `<option>` element.

```
function load_address() {
    var selected = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selected"));
    const options = document.getElementById('batch[]').options;
    Array.from(options).map((option) => {
        if(selected.indexOf(option.value) !== -1) {
            option.setAttribute("selected", "selected");
        }
    });
}
```